# Relation between Homotopy $\pi_0(G)$ and Surfaces of transitivity --- of Lorentz group $G$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, semi-riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry

### Homotopy $\pi_0(G)$ of Lorentz group $G$

We know the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) is an indefinite orthogonal group $O(1,3)$ with $\mathbf{R}$ coefficients, which Lie group topology has four connected pieces due to
$$
\pi_0(O(1,3))=\mathbf{Z}/2\oplus \mathbf{Z}/2
$$
The generators are called $P$ and $T$ in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Connected_components)

### Surfaces of transitivity of Lorentz group $G$

According to [surfaces of transitivity (of Lorentz group $G$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Surfaces_of_transitivity):
If a group $G$ acts on a space $V$, then a surface $S  ⊂  V$ is a  surface of transitivity if $S$ is invariant under $G$, i.e., $∀ g  ∈ G$, $∀s  ∈  S :  gs  ∈  S$, and for any two points $ s_1 ,  s_2  ∈  S$ there is a $g  ∈ G$ such that $gs_1  = s_2$. By definition of the Lorentz group, it preserves the quadratic form
$$Q(x) = x_0^2 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2.$$

The surfaces of transitivity of the orthochronous Lorentz group $O_+(1, 3)$, $Q(x) {{=}} const.$ of spacetime are the following:

- $Q(x) > 0, x_0  > 0$ is the upper branch of a hyperboloid of two sheets. Points on this sheet are separated from the origin by a future  time-like  vector.
- $Q(x) > 0, x_0 < 0$ is the lower branch of this hyperboloid. Points on this sheet are the past  time-like  vectors.
- $Q(x)= 0, x_0  > 0$ is the upper branch of the light cone, the future light cone.
- $Q(x)= 0, x_0  <0$ is the lower branch of the light cone, the past light cone.
- $Q(x)  <0  is a hyperboloid of one sheet. Points on this sheet are  space-like  separated from the origin.
- The origin $x_\mu  = 0$.

I am not sure how to count the number of surfaces of transitivity for the orthochronous Lorentz group $O_+(1, 3)$.

But according to [Wiki - surfaces of transitivity (of Lorentz group $G$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Surfaces_of_transitivity), for the full Lorentz group $O(1, 3)$, the surfaces of transitivity are only **four** since the transformation T takes an upper branch of a hyperboloid (cone) to a lower one and vice versa.

$$
\text{So the number of surfaces of transitivity for the full Lorentz group $O(1, 3)$ is 
4.}
$$
But how is this 4 counted? The transformation T can also bring the future light cone to the past light cone. So according to this logic,
$$
\text{we may only have 3 kinds of surfaces of transitivity? see below}
$$

1. $Q(x) > 0, x_0  > 0$ and $Q(x) > 0, x_0 < 0$  are the upper and lower branch of a hyperboloid of two sheets. Points on this sheet are separated from the origin by a future  time-like  vector. But the two sheets are related by the $T$ transformation.
2. $Q(x)= 0, x_0  > 0$ and $Q(x)= 0, x_0  <0$: the upper and lower branches of the light cone, the future light cone. But the two sheets are related by the $T$ transformation.
3. $Q(x)  <0  is a hyperboloid of one sheet. Points on this sheet are  space-like  separated from the origin.

### Question: Relation between $\pi_0(O(1,3))=\mathbf{Z}/2\oplus \mathbf{Z}/2$ and $O(1,3)'s$ Surfaces of transitivity.

My question is that how the four connected pieces  of Lorentz group $O(1,3)$ is related or established from the surfaces of transitivity of Lorentz group? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Surfaces_of_transitivity

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece of the puzzle there is the origin. I'm not sure if you can really call that a surface since it is 0-dimensional but it is present in the list on wikipedia so I assume that is the 4th kind of surface to which they refer.

On to how this relates to the connected components of $O(1,3)$. The best way to understand these components is by dividing the group up based on two properties. Firstly, as with the definite orthogonal group $O(n)$ some elements preserve orientation and some reverse it (i.e. they have determinant $\pm 1$) and the subgroup of those that preserve it, the *special* orthogonal group, is labelled $SO(1,3)$ and this is disconnected from the rest of the group. On the other hand we also have some elements which preserve the forward time direction (equally they preserve the forward light cone) and some which exchange the forward direction with the backward direction. The subgroup which preserves the time direction is the orthochronous group $O_+(1,3)$.

How do these interact? Well the intersection of these subgroups which we shall label $SO_+(1,3)$ is the elements which preserve both orientation and the forward light cone. This subgroup is connected and indeed it is the connected component of the identity. We could write all the components now as cosets of this component. If $A \in SO(1,3)$ which doesn't preserve the forward light cone and $B \in O_+(1,3)$ which doesn't preserve the orientation then the components are $SO_+(1,3)$, $A\cdot SO_+(1,3)$, $B\cdot SO_+(1,3)$, $AB\cdot SO_+(1,3)$ and for example $SO(1,3) = SO_+(1,3)\cup A\cdot SO_+(1,3)$.

So what have we seen through all this. Well firstly, the orientation preserving/not-preserving distinction doesn't make any difference to the orbits. $O(1,3)$, $SO(1,3)$ have the same "surfaces of transitivity". However, if we restrict to the orthochronous group some of the orbits are split into $2$. Specifically the light cone and the two-sheeted hyperboloids are split into their forward and backward components.

Comment: thanks so much I voted up - may accept soon if no better answer

Comment: you said "the special orthogonal group, is labelled (1,3) and this is disconnected from the rest of the group" But the (1,3) is itself disconnected as $_0(S(1,3))=/2$. So how does that affect your answer?

Comment: "The missing piece of the puzzle there is the origin. I'm not sure if you can really call that a surface since it is 0-dimensional but it is present in the list on wikipedia so I assume that is the 4th kind of surface to which they refer." But isnt light cone contains the origin, $_=0$, therefore, we only have 3 kinds of surfaces of transitivity: 2-sheet hyperbola, lightcone, 1-sheet hyperbola. Yes or no?

Comment: more importantly, how the distinct number of surfaces of transitivity relates to the homotopy 0()? Is it possible that we have only a kind of surfaces of transitivity, but with a nonzero $_0()\neq 0$?

Comment: When I say $SO(1,3)$ is disconnected from the rest of the group, I mean that $SO(1,3)$ contains exactly two connected components and nothing else. So its set complement consists of two other connected components. The origin is in a separate orbit from the rest of the light cone. Note that while there are infinitely may hyperboloids for each value of $Q(x)$. There is only one (or two for $O_+(1,3)$) orbits in the light cone minus the origin. So there are 4 kinds of orbits for $O(1,3)$, 1-sheeted hyperboloids, 2-sheeted hyperboloids, the light cone minus the origin and the origin itself.

Comment: The number doesn't directly relate to the homotopy. In this case we have a special relationship that the thing which disconnects $SO(1,3)$ is the same thing that joins the forward and backward directions into a single orbit. But this isn't a general pattern and indeed as we have seen there are two things causing the disconnected components in $O(1,3)$ and only one of them has anything to do with the number of components. What is true is that if the homotopy is trivial (i.e. the group is connected) then so are all its orbits. But that doesn't put a limit on how may types there are.

Comment: Also one thing to note. "Surfaces of transitivity" appears to be a physics term for what mathematicians would call orbits but I hadn't heard it before your question. Just to let you know that people may be confused by it.